# How do I finish these rough stairs?

Tags: stairs

I have done some research, and generally I understand that I need to install skirt boards in the spaces the builder left between the wall an the stairs, and I need to cut a skirt board for the outside edge of the lower stairs. I also *think* that I need to install treads and risers over the rough boards you see here ( I don't want carpet). The walls need handrails, and the exposed side of the stairs needs a banister. IF all of that is correct, I am still confused about some specific areas that I have labeled in the photos.

First, the stairs are all about 7" except for the first bottom step and the winder which are both 8". For the floor at the bottom, I plan on either staining the concrete or using vinyl stick on planks. Are these two 8" parts ok, or am I screwed?

Spots A and B: It seems like I would have a closed skirt board coming down from the upper stairs, and the have to somehow transition it to an open skirt at point A? And I have no idea about B. Maybe a newel would go there? But I think some sort of trim would still be needed. I just don't know what that would be.

Spot C: Am I supposed to just use like a really big tread on middle landing area?

Spot D: How do I finish that last step? I guess I can't really put a tread on it because then it would be higher than the rest of the floor. I will probably use vinyl planking on the upper floor, or possibly carpet.

Spot E: This is really just a question about the extra inch on the first step. I'm not sure if there is anything I need to do special here.

Spot F: I can't picture how I trim this area. I was thinking that the middle landing would use base board, but what do I do at the winder step up? Just run the base board vertically? Or is there something better for this spot?

[image: Upper stairs]

[image: middle landing]

[image: lower stairs view 1]

[image: lower stairs view 2]

[image: oh no head height]

Comment: Take a look at https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch03_SecR311.7.5 for stair riser/tread dimensional ranges, precision, etc. It brackets the stair riser heights as +/-3/16". It sets 7-3/4" as the maximum height.

Comment: What are your tread depths?

Comment: The tread depth is 10.25"

Comment: @popham thanks. I looked at that code, and I think I am in trouble. I added another picture that shows a spot where the head height is only 6'3".  Please tell me there is some sort of trick I can do to fix this?

Comment: Otherwise, I guess I need to have se sort of landing at the bottom, and that could bring that step height into range? I'm not sure about the 8" winder yet.

Comment: Usually rough/construction stair treads are removed and replaced with final finished material (though it would be unusual for rough risers as you have to be intended to be removed). You could simply cover these, but that will make the first riser even more than 8". Your flooring material will probably be > 1/4" thick, so if you _replace_ the treads, you'll be under 7-3/4" for that first step.

Comment: I assume you saw the part where 10" treads are only okay with nosings, where nose-less stairs like yours call for 11" treads.

Comment: Yes, as I understand it, that mean I just need to buy trade with a nose on them?
I guess my biggest concern now has become the head height. I can't seem to find any exceptions for that rule.

Comment: Your headroom is more like 6'-0". It's supposed to be measured from the imaginary line connecting the stair noses. If steeper stairs within spec can't get the clearance, then the solution is to remodel the ceiling or ignore the spec. I can't imagine a jurisdiction where that's okay, but you should verify that your code is in fact the International Residential Code.

Comment: Do you think I could possibly go with a 3 or 4 step winder to gain the clearance by reducing the height that the lower steps need to climb?

Comment: IRC R311.7.5.2.1: "Winder treads shall have a tread depth of not less than 6 inches at any point within the clear width of the stair." When the winder tread converges to a point, there's supposed to be a handrail sticking out to restrict access to the less-than-6" part. This would probably intrude into the 31-1/2" or 27" width prescribed in R311.7.1. And you still have to maintain the 10" depth along the "walkline" (center between handrail/wall or handrail/handrail). I would do a plan view CAD, but I'm pessimistic.

Comment: Is there headroom for a landing popping out into the lower floor area that changes direction of travel by 180 degrees instead of the current 90 degrees?

Comment: Is that a header at your "D"? It looks like there could be some headroom to claw back by pulling the first step back to the door threshold. Not enough, it doesn't look like. From each of those 5 upper steps, you've got an additional 3/4" to claw back. Maybe that gets you close.

Comment: Estimating that threshold claw back at 6", I get (6+5*0.75)*7.75/10 = 7.5". My 6'-0" estimate + that 7.6" gets you real close to the 6'-8" headroom spec. If tread heights of exactly 7-3/4" don't land well at the bottom, however....